# How to create StackDriver Workspace in GCP using API or Terraform Template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I would like to create a Stackdriver Workpace programmatically by Using Scripts, Terraform template or API as I need to avoid manual steps to create Stackdriver workspace for each projects manually. It should be a part of terraform or API to create it automatically for the projects required Stackdriver monitoring

Can any one provide a solution or suggestions for the same.

Thank you.

Ashok

Comment: I need the same thing, but as far as I know, the Google API does not support creating a workspace so neither does Terraform. In fact, the only way that you can create a workspace is via the Web Console. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/2605

Answer (score 4):

This feature is not available yet. more info [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/2605)